# Scriptable object doesn't work on build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm hoping this might be something simple I'm missing.

I have a ScriptableObject script that looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Item: ScriptableObject
{
    public string iname;
    public int iindex;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public GameObject itemObject;
    public int value;
    public string description;
    public itemType itemtype;

    public enum itemType
    {

        Consumable,
        Equippable,
    }

}
```

This works great in the editor, but if I publish to Android or Windows any script that references the ScriptableObject, it does not work. What am I missing?

For example the following block of code does not seem to execute at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int lootnum = Random.Range(0, 4);


    slot1 = itemdb[lootnum];
    tlist[i] = itemdb[lootnum];
    slotlist[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = itemdb[lootnum].sprite;
    slotlist[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
}
```

Those lists in the code are of the type Item defined in the above script. I'm not sure how to debug this as I get no errors or warnings in the editor.

Here is the script which populates the inventory. There's a bit of junk in there but it definitley works fine pressing play in the editor. Just not on build.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {


    public int invSize;
    public Item slot1;
    public Item tslot1;
    public Item tslot2;
     public Item tslot3;
    public GameObject t1;
    public GameObject t2;
    public GameObject t3;
    public Sprite itemsprite;
    public List<Item> itemdb = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> tlist = new List<Item>();
    public Text stext;
    public Text description;
    public Item selectItem;
    public GameObject selectSlot;
    public Object test2;

    public List<GameObject> slotlist = new List<GameObject>();


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void addItem(Item itemToAdd)
    {
        //items.Add(itemdb[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            if (items[i] == null)
            {
                items[i] = itemToAdd;
                itemsprite = itemToAdd.sprite;

                return;
            }
        }
    }


    public void GenTreasure()
    {





        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int lootnum = Random.Range(0, 4);


            slot1 = itemdb[lootnum];
            tlist[i] = itemdb[lootnum];
            slotlist[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = itemdb[lootnum].sprite;
            slotlist[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
        }

    }


    public void Uptext(int indexx)
    {
        stext.text = tlist[indexx].iname;
        selectItem = tlist[indexx];
        selectSlot = slotlist[indexx];
        description.text = selectItem.description;
    }

    public void Take(int index)
    {
        //items.Add(selectItem);
        for (int i = 0; i < invSize; i++)
        {

            if (items[i] == null)
            {
                items[i] = selectItem;
                //   itemsprite = itemToAdd.sprite;
                selectItem = null;
                //   tlist[i] = null;
                //    slotlist[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = null;
                selectSlot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;

                return;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Does it produce an error, does it simply not show up?

Comment: The inventory system works fine if i hit play in the editor. Once built, the item slots don't initialise or assign sprites etc. It's like the item class script isn't included in the build? The script is not in the scene if that matters

Comment: I don't think we can help with only this much information. What triggers the code you showed us? Can you just show the rest of the class?

Comment: Posted the rest of the inventory class. GenTreasure is called when the player triggers a treasure chest. The item assets themselves are assigned in the editor

Answer (score 0):

If the script is not in the scene, how does it get loaded? Is it using an asset bundle? If that is the case, then it's possible that the class is being stripped from the build. You can include the class in your link.xml to make sure it's included. Another option is to simply reference the script in an included scene anywhere.